# Securing multiple systems accessing the same data

Tags: web-application, webserver, permissions

I'm hitting a roadblock when it comes to security for managing scoped permissions for servers.

Right now I run a community which can create sub-servers. So community A can allow certain users to moderate it, change settings, invite users, read logs etc for their own sub-server, but not others.

My current system has a global user, this user has permissions structured similar to this:

```
{
 "id" :"their unique id",
 "username" : "username",
 "globalRole" : "user",
 "permissions": [
   {
      "resource" : "guilds_id_here",
      "permissions" : [
         {
           "resource" : "guild.logs",
           "read" : true,
           "write" : false
          }
       ]

    }
  ]
}
```

A single user has access based on 'resources', and when they attempt to modify, read or do anything through my API or Socket, i check if they have access to the resource they're modifying.

This is pretty easy for me to manage permissions through the API as i intercept the request, grab the resource and see if they're permitted to perform the action they're trying to do, such as read a log or invite a user and then either reject the API call before it ever reaches the controller.

The main issue I'm now having is with maintaining multiple means of access, I now have the REST API and a WebSocket which can access the same kinds of data depending on where they're accessing the guild from.

So now the permission system has become significantly more complicated and isnt as easy as intercepting a request from the REST API and blocking it, i now have two permission checking systems which I feel is wrong and breaks the DRY Principle.

I'd like to learn if there are any industry standards for multiple means of accessing data. Should I build a resource manager which always needs credentials and the target resource, and then have a system user for internal access or is there an easier standard for tight nit control over who can do what based on the permissions they have for a specific resource.

The end goal is to be able to grant permission to an object and properly filter out data that is authorised for the user requesting data.

Comment: How is the user sending their permissions? As a cookie? In the HTTP Authorization header?

Comment: For the API they have an Application ID, Token and Username to verify their identity. Works the same with the Socket authentication as well.

Through the headers of the request

Comment: Reason its an Application ID is i allow users to create sub identities to access this information outside of the server for their own projects.

Comment: Normal practice would be to make your REST API a layer over the existing API, or to create a shared library level that underlies both APIs, so that you're only implementing access control _once_ and the two front-end APIs defer to that common layer.  Re-implementing shared functionality is a recipe for ouch.